# How can I print base64 string that returns from API call with react-native-print?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, base64

Response is meant to be passed as pdf or HTML String and I don't want to use react-native-pdf for conversion. Decoding to HTML String would be OK too but I couldn't find a way to decode base64 String to HTML String.

Comment: `base64 string` _is_ string... You want to decode it or something?

Comment: @Justinas yes, I want to decode it.

Comment: For decoding using javascript use [atob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob)